# Best method of saving data

Tags: python, serialization, save

I've made a class in which I want to keep track of stats of students. I intend to make a GUI later to manipulate this data.

My main question is: what is the best way to save and later retrieve this data?

I've read about pickle and JSON, but I don't really get how they work (especially about how they save the data, like in which format and where).

Comment: Any reason not to use sqlite, which is shipped with Python?

Comment: Storing and retrieving of data is called "serialization", I took the liberty to add that to the tags. Using a websearch (or the Powerz of the Lazyweb as below), you will find lots of info on that topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For persistent data (storing info about students), a database is a good choice. As already mentioned, Python comes shipped with Sqlite3 which is often good enough, for development purposes at least.

Introducing Sqlite to Python is easy - just import the library in your source code file and open a connection to your database. Refer to the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

**EDIT**: Found [a new tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/) about Python + Sqlite that seems good.

Answer (score 20):

If your data are pretty simple, like just collections of collections of strings or numbers, I would use json. What JSON is, is a string representation of simple data types and combinations of simple data types. Once you use the `json` module to convert your data to a string, you write it to a file yourself.

It's super simple:

```
>>> my_data = [range(5) for i in range(5)]
>>> my_data
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(my_data)
'[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]'
```

Then just write that string to a file. When you want to reload it, like so:

```
>>> import json
>>> string_from_file
'[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]'
>>> my_saved_data = json.loads(string_from_file)
>>> my_saved_data
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

If your data are more complicated, and involves classes other than the built-in collection objects, pickle is a better choice. One **very important** thing to know about pickle is that there are security vulnerabilities in pickle, and it's a bad idea to unpickle anything you yourself didn't pickle. `pickle` is vulnerable to the security problems detailed in this article: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2013/01/31/what-the-rails-security-issue-means-for-your-startup/

If the size of your data is very large, or you will be saving/loading it frequently, or for any reason using json and saving to a local file is inadequate, then a database will be the way to go.

Comment: I think JSON is a good choice. In terms of complexity, it's somewhele between CSV and XML. I consider CSV a bit too simple for many uses, it's hard to represent "natural" structures in it. The upside of XML is that everything and the kitchensink can import/export it or use it as protocol base, so it's a powerful metaformat, but it's also more complicated.

Comment: Nice thing about JSON is that, unlike Pickle, it is language-agnostic.

Comment: This answer is the one I would recommend to anyone here. Also, if you have numpy arrays and such, json-tricks is a really good package.

Comment: Maybe also mention that pickles can be incompatible even between different Python versions.

Answer (score 2):

You also may use [csv files](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. It depends on what you need.

Comment: The problem with CSV is that it is unsuitable for structured data. If you can get by with saving just a single two-dimensional array (or a handful of arrays, if you use a separate CSV file for each), CSV is fine; but it's unsuitable for anything with more dimensions or structure within individual fields.

Answer (score 2):

Use a database. SQLAlchemy with SQLight is a good start. You'll end up there in the end anyway.

*or*

Dump everything out with the pickle module. (there really isn't anything to understand, you save objects and then load them again, it's really simple).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pickling](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), Python's serialization mechanism:

> The pickle module implements a fundamental, but powerful algorithm for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure. “Pickling” is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is converted into a byte stream, and “unpickling” is the inverse operation, whereby a byte stream is converted back into an object hierarchy. Pickling (and unpickling) is alternatively known as “serialization”, “marshalling,” [1] or “flattening”, however, to avoid confusion, the terms used here are “pickling” and “unpickling”.

Comment: Pickles are fine for short-term local storage, but  don't scale well to large data amounts, network concurrency, and/or different Python versions.