# How can I make a Python program so that even after termination, the variable, list and other objects' values do not reset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, persistence, reset, termination

## For example,

```
x = 0
for i in range(5):
   x += 1
print(x)
```

Here, I want the value of x to remain 5 and not reset to 0 after the program terminates, just the way normal applications do with your settings, personal info etc.

Comment: But when you run it again, you immediately set `x = 0`, so how would you know? Maybe [reading through this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509269/best-method-of-saving-data) would help.

Comment: @MarkMeyer you have a point though.. thanks!

Comment: Normal applications don't work that way, they use some form of *data persistence.* This could be anything as simple as a text file that you read to load the values or a full-fledge database and beyond

Answer (score 2):

After a program terminates, anything that was in its memory is gone.  The simplest way to persist data permanently is to write it to a file, which you can read about here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

For example:

```
try:
    with open("save.txt") as save:
        x = int(save.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("No save file found, starting at 0")
    x = 0

for i in range(5):
    x += 1
print(x)

with open("save.txt", "w") as save:
    save.write(str(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a database! You can try storing your data in a database like MongoDB. Another thing you can do is create a local file as mentioned by @Samwise.
But it might be better to use a database as it will help in learning how to use it if you are new to databases. You can try using MongoDB with `pymongo`

#### Edit

Extending @Samwise's answer. You might want to store multiple values in your local file. To do this try creating a JSON or YAML file. For JSON files you can use the standard `json` library and for YAML search for one on PyPI