# Would like yo get advice for attached python program. Can we use dictionary as database for very basic login system program?

Tags: python

I am trying to create login system program, where "name", "email" and "password" has to be taken fron user as input and save as Dictionary in text file. I am stuck on how to assign each dicitionary a variable.
Also, once the user comes again after registration, there should be password check done against the dictionary text file which i am not sure. Pls look into the below code and assist?

```py
#! usr/bin/python3
# Login project sample
import json
def login():

    print("Welcome to login system")
    New_user = input("Are you a new user? type yes or no: ")
    if New_user == "yes":
        a = {}
        Name = input("Enter your name: ")
        Email = input("Enter the email: ")
        Password = input("Enter the password: ")
        a["Name"] = (Name)
        a["Email"] = (Email)
        a["Password"] = (Password)
        print(a)
        with open("login.txt", "a+") as f:
            f.seek(0)
            data = f.read(100)
            if len(data) > 0:
                f.write("\n")
                x = str(range(1,100))
                f.write(x + "=" + json.dumps(a))
                x = x + 1
    else:
        b={}
        def login1():

            Email = input("Enter the email: ")
            Password = input("Enter the password: ")
            b["Email"] = (Email)
            b["Password"] = (Password)
            with open("login.txt", "r") as r:
                f.seek(0)
                i = range(100)
                if i.keys() in b.keys() and i.value() in b.value():
                    print("Login is successfull")
                else:
                    login1()
login()
```

Comment: How do you intend to use such database? For example, will it be hosted publicly on the Internet or will it be used only locally by a closed set of users? Will the authentication grant users access to any sensitive data (how much ok are you with someone breaking into it)? Etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best method of saving data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509269/best-method-of-saving-data)

Comment: Hi Pawel, Thank you for the response. I am a newbie to Python and hence thought of using .txt file database for now for this program. This is sample program hosted internally and have sample data in it. Later I'll try to use MariaDB/SQL for database. Wanted to understand if .txt file as the database is possible for a beginner like me before exploring database options.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against 1) using dictionary as a way of persistently storing authentication data, 2) storing users password directly in such database.

If you don't really need to use a dictionary then some simple solution like `sqlite` (.db file instead of .txt file) with some hashing library can help you achieve your goal. The code could look something like that:

```
import sqlite3
import hashlib


def create_table():
    query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS login"
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()

    query = "CREATE TABLE login(name VARCHAR DEFAULT '', email VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE, password VARCHAR NOT NULL)"
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()

def add_user(name, email, raw_password):
    query = "INSERT INTO login (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
    hashed_password = hashlib.sha256(raw_password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    cursor.execute(query, (name, email, hashed_password))
    conn.commit()

def check_user(name, email, raw_password):
    query = 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE name = ? AND email = ? AND password = ?'
    hashed_password = hashlib.sha256(raw_password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    cursor.execute(query, (name, email, hashed_password))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    print('[DEBUG][check] result:', result)
    return result

def login():
    answer = input("Login (Y/N): ")
    if answer.lower() == "y":
        name = input("Name: ")
        email = input("Email: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        if check_user(name, email, password):
            print("Email correct!")
            print("Password correct!")
            print("Logging in...")
        else:
            print("Something wrong")

# --- main ---

conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

create_table()  # use only once

name = input("New name: ")
email = input("New email: ")
password = input("New password: ")

add_user(name, email, password)

login()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much... Will take a look